# how to apply 2 text styles to a label in iphone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

i have a tableview. in cell i am displaying some string data from xml.
 in that string some italic tags and some normal tags r there.
 but when i try to display the entire string it is displayed in normal text and not getting italic text. 
i tried by taking 2 labels one with italic text and another with normal text and appending these 2 labels but i am getting entire string as italic.

how can we apply 2 styles in a label

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show some code of how you creating and styling your UILabel's?

Comment: If this question no longer requires additional answers, please mark the appropriate post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the UILabel control does not support "rich text." You cannot have some text italic and some normal in the same UILabel.

Three20 has a label that supports this, however:

http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_styled_text_label.php